# Doesn't Postgres reuse unique indexes for unique key constraint?

Tags: postgresql

Having experience with Oracle I assumed that each unique constraint would reuse unique index.

I created schema population script that creates named unique index and then same unique constraint. In that way I hoped to set index name explicitly rather than relay on Postgres default naming schema.

As experiment was shown I got two indexes with same definition in a result:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX agent_ux ON agent (branch_id, initials);
ALTER TABLE agent ADD CONSTRAINT agent_uk UNIQUE (branch_id, initials);

select indexname from pg_indexes where tablename = 'agent';
agent_ux
agent_uk
```

Doesn't Postgres reuse unique indexes for unique key constraint?

**NOTE** I can't drop index, corresponding to unique constraint (error says about related constraint), but index is automatically deleted if I delete constraint.

Comment: @wildplasser Can you write answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres, creating a UNIQUE constraint automatically creates an index. You can also create the constraint by *promoting* an existing index, using the `ALTER TABLE ttt add constraint ccc USING xxx` syntax: [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

---

```
ALTER TABLE agent
   ADD CONSTRAINT agent_uk UNIQUE USING agent_ux;
```

---

[untested]